# paintComponent() slowing down after adding a image to the background

Tags: java, image, draw, paintcomponent

I'm creating an game in Java in a JPanel that takes user input to change player coordinates. In the JPanel I create, I say

```
        Thread gameThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(true){
                frameCount++;
                repaint();
                code();
                try{
                    Thread.sleep((long)(1000/Main.UPDATE_RATE));
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    };
```

Where repaint() is where I update the JPanel and code() is where I process the information.

Right now, I have some images and rectangles that are being placed on the JPanel, and the repaint() and code() methods are running at the same speed. However, after I add

```
    for(int y = 0; y < screenHeight; y += backgroundHeight){
        for(int x = 0 - getBackgroundDisplacement() - backgroundWidth; x < screenWidth; x += backgroundWidth){
            g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, null);

        }
    }
```

the repaint() runs about 2/3 the speed of the code().

Is there any reason why the paint would slow down so much for adding a few images (around 4) to the background?

Comment: How large is the background image? Your code is using a nested loop - consider drawing your tiles(?) to a single background Image once (outside of any EDT painting method), then draw that Image with a single `drawImage` call in `paintComponent`

Comment: @copeg What I tried doing was adding one larger image to the background (as opposed to four) instead the nested for loop but I still had the same amount of lag involved.

Comment: How are you defining `lag`? Does this affect user interaction? Post any updated code, or better yet, post an [mcve]

Comment: @copeg in my code, I put a variable to increase by one every time code() ran and a variable for draw(). After 5000 ticks of code(), draw() had about 3000 runs. However, I went home and tried the same code on my home computer and it ran with no issues...

Comment: @copeg Now I'm confused as to why my laptop wouldn't run it as well as my desktop as it isn't a bad laptop.

Comment: Counting the number of times code running between 2 different threads is ran may not be the ideal way to test `lag` (`lag` in my opinion would be unresponsive user interface eg paintComponent is taking too long). It is unclear as to your refresh rate - if this is extremely fast than painting may not be able to catch up.